# I am getting undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

```
firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen) => {
const { notification } = notificationOpen;
notification.android.setChannelId('notificationId');
this.props.navigation.navigate("LoginScreen");});
```

I am facing issues of undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate') while clicking on firebase notification in react native

Answer (score 0):

Without any futher informations, the error is clear. You're trying to get a property of your content called `navigation`. But, in this context, it's not defined or not accessible.

To get the content of your property, make sure it's defined clearly in your content and accessible inside of your function .
Then you should be able to use the function `navigate('LoginScreen')` related to your property.

Comment: I am able to use navigate function in other screen but in App.js file i am getting this error while clicking on firebase notification. please help me.

Comment: Are the notifications a 'new page' ? If so then the your property doesn't exist.
If not, do you have `Arrow function` before your code ? Please update your post with more informations, code details, etc.

Comment: backgroundNotificationListener(navigation) {
        firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen) => {
            const { notification } = notificationOpen;
            notification.android.setChannelId('notificationId');
            const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
                index: 0,
                actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'LoginScreen' })],
            });
            this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
            //this.props.navigation.navigate("LoginScreen");
        });
    }  without arrow function

Comment: The first function you're using is an `Arrow function`... . Please update your post or post the code in pastbin or codepen.