# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

I have been experimenting on a react-native project. I have a basic login screen with two buttons, one to login and one to take you to the "forgot password" screen. What is troubling me is that the login button works normally, but the forgot password button gives the error written in the title.

Login screen:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import {
  Icon, Text, Item, Input, Button
} from 'native-base';
import { firebaseAuth } from '../../environment/config';

export default class Login extends React.Component {
  state = {
    email: '', password: '', errorMessage: null
  };

  handleLogin = () => {
    const { email } = this.state;
    const { password } = this.state;
    firebaseAuth
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(() => {
        const { navigation } = this.props;
        navigation.navigate('Authentication');
      })
      .catch(error => this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message }));
  };

  forgotPass = () => {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    navigation.navigate('ForgotPassword');
  };

  render() {
    const { errorMessage } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {/* <Text style={styles.heading}>Login</Text> */}
        {errorMessage && <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>{errorMessage}</Text>}
        <Item>
          <Icon active name="person" />
          <Input
            autoCapitalize="none"
            placeholder="Email"
            onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })}
            value={this.email}
          />
        </Item>
        <Item>
          <Icon active name="lock" />
          <Input
            secureTextEntry
            autoCapitalize="none"
            placeholder="Password"
            onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })}
            value={this.password}
          />
        </Item>

        <Button
          transparent
          dark
          style={styles.forgotBtn}
          onPress={this.forgotPass}
        >
          <Text>Forgot Password </Text>
        </Button>
        <Button
          style={styles.signupBtn}
          rounded
          dark
          block
          onPress={this.handleLogin}
        >
          <Text>Log In </Text>
        </Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and the App.js

```
const SwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    Loading,
    SignUp,
    Login,
    Main,
    Authentication,
    LoginRegisterComponent,
    ForgotPassword
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Loading',
    headerMode: 'none'
  }
);

const App = createAppContainer(SwitchNavigator);
export default App;
```

I have checked other questions that are similar to this one :
[undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55221232/undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-navigation-navigate)
&& 
[I am getting undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56356203/i-am-getting-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-this-props-navigation-navig)

The answers given there aren't of much help and I cannot understand why the one button is working and the other one is not.

Comment: facing same issue